# Vboxnet0 unmanaged disapear since last update

Tags: networking, virtualbox, network-manager

I just updated my Ubuntu OS. And all my virtual machines can't access the host now. All VMs can ping between each other but no VM can ping host (192.168.56.1). And host can't ping any VM.

Before the update I had an unmanaged network interface in the right corner of my screen in the network manager menu. This icon disappeared since the update.

How to solve this problem? I use a "host-only network" with a NAT network because I usually change my host connection between Wired, Wifi and Modem. And most importantly I don't want use bridge network to allow other people to access to my personal VM.

I use Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.02 LTS and Virtualbox 5.1.24.

Answer (score 1):

You might be running into the following issue https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16911 for VirtualBox 5.1.24.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45266699/78450 for a temporary workaround.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.